# PDO DBLIB E CODIFICACAO UTF-8

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, utf-8

Estou em um projeto usando UBUNTU-SERVER 64bits como WEBSERVER.
No projeto escolhi o banco de dados Microsoft Sql Server 2012 a qual possuo uma licença de uso adquirida a pouco tempo.

Com muito esforço consegui a conexão usando algumas libs como freetds sybase... para PHP-7. Porém estou com erro de codificação de caracteres.
Já setei na string de conexao o parametro UTF-8 e não obtive sucesso! Alguém já passou pelo mesmo problema e conseguiu solucionar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'      => 'dblib:host=192.168.1.1:1433;dbname=TOESTE;charset=UTF-8',
    'hostname' => 'dblib:host=192.168.1.1:1433;dbname=TOESTE;charset=UTF-8',
    'port'     => '1433',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'xxxxxx',
    'database' => 'TOESTE',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt'  => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: O driver `sqlsrv` não funciona? só o `dblib`?

Comment: sqlsrv não é suportado de acordo com oq andei pesquisando. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903148/ubuntu-php-and-sqlsrv-connect

Comment: Muda a string `dblib:host ....` por `sqlsrv:host ....` http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php e http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php. No pior caso pode usar o ODBC.

Comment: Message: Undefined class constant 'SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8'

Filename: /webserver/development/system/database/drivers/pdo/subdrivers/pdo_sqlsrv_driver.php<br />

Removendo da config o char-set

A Database Error Occurred

could not find driver

Comment: vc trocou o dns? como fez?

Comment: $db['default'] = array(
 'dsn'    => 'sqlsrv:host=192.168.1.1:1433;dbname=TRANSOESTE',
 'hostname' => 'sqlsrv:host=192.168.1.1:1433;dbname=TRANSOESTE',
 'port'    => '1433',
 'username' => 'sa',
 'password' => '354263',
 'database' => 'TRANSOESTE',
 'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => FALSE,
 'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => '',
 'dbcollat' => '',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt'  => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);

Comment: A base está utf-8 ? o arquivo php também?

Comment: o banco de dados está como Latin1_General_CI_AS
<meta charset="utf-8">
o php vou confirmar mas quando uso o banco mysql nao tenho esse problema.

Comment: Acredito que esse seja o problema, pode fazer um teste, criar um banco novo com o encode utf-8 e criar uma tabela e adicionar alguns registros e listar no php e ver se o problema com a codificação continua.

Comment: Não o problema é realmente na lib de conexao. Estou usando o mesmo banco em outro servidor web em que roda a lib mssql e não tenho esse problema. o php está ok tb. estava vendo em um site e me parece q essa lib nao suporta utf-8 http://www.synet.sk/php/en/230-php-drivers-for-microsoft-sql-server-mssql-sqlsrv-utf8

Comment: Isso é ajax Rafael?

Comment: Não. isso é o array de configuração de conexão do framework.

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se já resolveram esse problema, mas vou deixar aqui uma possível solução:

A instalação padrão do freetds utiliza a versão 4.2 do TDS que deve funcionar pra todas as versões do SQL Server. O problema aqui é que essa versão não tem suporte para caracteres UTF-8 ou acentuações de qualquer tipo. Pra corrigir isso vc pode informar a versão do TDS no DSN de conexão:

```
dblib:version=7.0;charset=UTF-8;host=domain.example.com;dbname=example;
```

Ou alterar o arquivo `freetds.conf`, na configuração `[global]` em `tds version`, colocar a versão correta de acordo com a versão do SQL que está utilizando. Pra saber a versão correta, dê uma olhada aqui:

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm