# Problemas com encoding SQL Server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou realizando uma consulta em um banco de dados Sql Server, porém os caracteres especiais são retornados da seguinte forma:

```
MAR�O
```

ao invés de

```
MARÇO
```

Consegui consertar utilizando a função `utf8_encode()`, porém não quero ter que ficar tratando cada resultado, e realizando algumas pesquisas entendi que é possível fazer alguma configuração na conexão para que as informações já venham com `encoding` correto, porém ainda não consegui aplicar. Segue minha classe de conexão para melhor visualização:

```
<?php

class pdo_dblib_mssql {

    private $db;
    private $cTransID;
    private $hostname;
    private $port;
    private $dbname;
    private $username;
    private $pwd;
    private $table;
    private $columns;
    private $where = array();
    private $childTrans = array();

    public function __construct($data, $table) {
        $this->hostname = $data['host'];
        $this->port = $data['port'];
        $this->dbname = $data['schema'];
        $this->username = $data['user'];
        $this->pwd = $data['password'];

        $this->table = $table;

        $this->connect();
    }

    public function connect() {
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO("dblib:host=$this->hostname:$this->port;dbname=$this->dbname", "$this->username", "$this->pwd");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->logsys .= "\n Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function beginTransaction() {

        $cAlphanum = "AaBbCc0Dd1EeF2fG3gH4hI5iJ6jK7kLlM8mN9nOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz";
        $this->cTransID = "T" . substr(str_shuffle($cAlphanum), 0, 7);

        array_unshift($this->childTrans, $this->cTransID);

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("BEGIN TRAN [$this->cTransID];");
        return $stmt->execute();
    }

    public function rollBack() {

        while (count($this->childTrans) > 0) {
            $cTmp = array_shift($this->childTrans);
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("ROLLBACK TRAN [$cTmp];");
            $stmt->execute();
        }

        return $stmt;
    }

    public function commit() {

        while (count($this->childTrans) > 0) {
            $cTmp = array_shift($this->childTrans);
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("COMMIT TRAN [$cTmp];");
            $stmt->execute();
        }

        return $stmt;
    }

    public function close() {
        $this->db = null;
    }

    public function select($columns){
        $this->columns = $columns;

        return $this;
    }

    public function where($column, $value, $op = "=") {
        $this->where[] = "$column $op '$value'";
        return $this;
    }

    public function get(){
        $sql = "SELECT " . implode(", ", $this->columns) . " FROM $this->table WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $this->where);
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $ret = $stmt->fetchAll();

        var_dump($ret);die;
    }
}
```

Obs: Esse banco de dados é de terceiros, que me disponibiliza uma `view` para consulta, por isso maiores configurações do lado do banco não são possíveis.

O `collation` da `view` é `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

É possível tratar esses caracteres automaticamente de alguma forma, realizando alguma configuração na conexão ou antes de realizar a consulta?

Comment: relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115042/pdo-dblib-e-codificacao-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Tentou?

```
setAttribute( PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8 );
```

Comment: retornou o seguinte erro: `Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8'`